# Uploading file to Laravel-Backpack/Settings?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I may miss something but I cannot get the type "image" to work with Laravel-Backpack/Settings. It just saves the base64 image data directly into the database

I've tried:

- Create a mutator named setValueAttribute(), nothing happens
- Create a mutator named setHomeVideoAttribute() (name of the setting field), nothing happens

I searched everywhere, also searched in issue for tutorial/help and nothing is there.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: use this add-on https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/FileManager to manage your file upload, read this guide https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#upload for setup your configuration file uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just hit the same issue, but unfortunately the above answers haven't understood the scenario or question. I've looked through the documentation myself, and not found anything useful, I would guess image uploads are either not supported or an after thought for the package.

That said it can be made to work without too much fuss.

If you haven't already done so, publish the service provider for the settings package. This is so we can shortly control the default Crud Controller being instantiated by default. Publish it by running:

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\Settings\SettingsServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

You should now have a routes file published: `routes/backpack/settings.php`.

Create a new model, it should extend from the default backpack settings model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class Setting extends \Backpack\Settings\app\Models\Setting
{

}
```

We need one more file to completely overwrite the settings functionality (however we'll inherit all of it's behaviour).

Create a new Crud Controller to replace the default one, replacing the model it points to as shown on the first line of the set-up method:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Setting;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;
use Backpack\Settings\app\Http\Controllers\SettingCrudController;

class SettingsCrudController extends SettingCrudController
{
    public function setup()
    {
        CRUD::setModel(Setting::class);
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings(trans('backpack::settings.setting_singular'), trans('backpack::settings.setting_plural'));
        CRUD::setRoute(backpack_url(config('backpack.settings.route')));
    }
}
```

To make backpack pick this up, edit (namespace, and model name) your newly created `routes/backpack/settings.php` file to point to your new `SettingCrudController`:

```php
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Backpack\Settings Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are
| handled by the Backpack\Settings package.
|
*/

Route::group([
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => ['web', backpack_middleware()],
], function () {
    Route::crud(config('backpack.settings.route'), 'SettingsCrudController');
});
```

Backpack will now have started using your newly defined model and crud controller.

From here we can begin to solve the actual problem at hand. We need to add a mutator to your newly created model for the value method. The settings package stores all its data here (value field) regardless of type, so we **must** make additional checks we're dealing with an image. Thankfully field information will be JSON encoded in an adjacent DB column. Otherwise the code is similar to documentation for the main backpack repo for dealing with images.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class Setting extends \Backpack\Settings\app\Models\Setting
{
    /**
     * For image uploads.
     * See https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#image-1
     *
     * Since value is used between all settings of all types we need be more
     * clever about how we save our data.
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setValueAttribute($value)
    {
        // Handle all none image fields
        $fieldConfiguration = json_decode($this->field);
        if ($fieldConfiguration->type !== 'image') {
            // this is the default behaviour
            $this->attributes['value'] = $value;
        }

        // We can assume we're dealing with an image from this point on
        $disk = config('backpack.base.root_disk_name');
        $destinationPath = "public/uploads/frontend/logo";

        // We're deleting the image
        if ($value === null) {
            Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->value);
            $this->attributes['value'] = null;
        }

        // Backpack-Settings attempts to save the image as base 64.
        if (Str::startsWith($value, 'data:image'))
        {
            $image = Image::make($value)->encode('jpg', 100);
            $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
            $internalFilepath = "{$destinationPath}/{$filename}";

            Storage::disk($disk)->put($internalFilepath, $image->stream());
            Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->value);

            // 4. Save the public path to the database
            // but first, remove "public/" from the path, since we're pointing to it
            // from the root folder; that way, what gets saved in the db
            // is the public URL (everything that comes after the domain name)
            $publicDestinationPath = Str::replaceFirst('public/', '', $destinationPath);
            $this->attributes['value'] = "{$publicDestinationPath}/{$filename}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and sets a great example for others to follow.

Answer (score -1):

According to `Backpack file upload` you want to use additional package [FileManager](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/FileManager) to mange upload files. If you upload single file the you can use field type `upload`. check backpack documentation for more information [link](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#upload)